# Group Rows in Excel by same content in one column, but leave the top column visible

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I'm certainly not an expert on excel and I'm very much in need of help.

I'm building a database of companies in column B, with the columns thereafter listing key contacts in those business by position (with conditional formatting) but some positions have more than one incumbent and therefore I need to group those under a single company entry.

Is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[Database with group by ARRK Europe (A12-14)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C86C.png)

In this example when the group is minimised, there is no ARRK present on screen. Whereas I would like cell A12 to remain visible but those below to be minimised.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) would do what you're after, although your question isn't entirely clear. Perhaps you could add links to images showing what you have at the moment and a clearer description (or mock-up) of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @3N1GM4, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I've now uploaded a screenshot of my database and the issue at hand. I want row A12 to remain visible if possible.

Comment: Will the data will always be **sorted** by the company name? Can we use a **helper column**?

Comment: @BranislavKollár The data can be sorted by company name but I would also like it to be sorted by color or location. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is sorted, you can use `COUNTIF` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) with expandable range ([ExcelIsFun video Excel Magic Trick 567](https://youtu.be/cdWpJM5h1UI?t=56s)), to get *how many times until here, the value appeared*.

### Adding helper column with COUNTIF

So in the helper column you can write a formula for Company name (column B):

`=COUNTIF($B$3:B9;B9)` to get following in row 9. Notice the **locked-$B$3** : **B9-relative** in the first argument:

[image]

### Filter the results

Then you can filter the 1's to get the first ones.